# FLTK on Ubuntu 18.04: Set icon's popup text on dock

Tags: icons, gtk, ubuntu-18.04, gnome, fltk

I'm using [FLTK 1.3.4](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libfltk1.3) on Ubuntu 18.04.

My project develops a desktop app with GUI using FLTK. When the app is started, its default icon on the dock is a "stop" sign. When you hover your mouse on it, its default popup text is "FLTK". See the screenshot below:

[image: adjuster example 01]

I'm using FLTK's [adjuster example](https://github.com/fltk/fltk/blob/master/test/adjuster.cxx) to show this.

I want to use my own icon and change the text to something else. I've learned that the API [`void Fl_Window::icon(const Fl_RGB_Image * icon)`](https://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/classFl__Window.html#a508f3acd43f9b365d35897b5ec197dbe) can set the icon, but I haven't figured out how to change the hovering text. I've tried ``Fl_Window::label`and`Fl_Window::iconlabel` but they don't work.

**Does anyone know where I should look at?**

I have read [this document](https://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/osissues.html#osissues_unix) which gave me the hint of using `Fl_Window::icon()` but it doesn't mention how to set the text.

I guess I may also need to look at the GTK API (My system is using GTK 3), but after skimming the APIs on [this page](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/), I didn't find anything.

I also tried the https://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/classFl__Window.html#a9718a55f909d150394f4a67ba762aa0c`Fl_Window`'s constructor that accepts the window title, but it doesn't change the icon's hover text, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking around, this can be set using the method [`Fl_Window::xclass`](https://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/classFl__Window.html#a913bb4f81e4627e5b4a860ef78bca1ff). Its source code is [here](https://github.com/fltk/fltk/blob/release-1.3.5/src/Fl_Window.cxx#L244-L280).

The `xclass` string is used [here](https://github.com/fltk/fltk/blob/release-1.3.5/src/Fl_x.cxx#L2519-L2520):

```cpp
      XChangeProperty(fl_display, xp->xid, XA_WM_CLASS, XA_STRING, 8, 0,
                      (unsigned char *)buffer, len * 2 + 2);
```

This is an X Window API call. The `XA_WM_CLASS` property is the "Application class and name for resource database lookup." It is discussed in *Chapter 12. Interclient Communication* in the book *Xlib Programming Manual for Version 11 of the X Window System, Vol. 1*.